# Authorize doesn't work with empty credentials

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I have a .net 4.7.2 web api deployed on IIS with Windows authentication.

When I open it, if I valid authentication form with empty user and password, it works, swagger page is displayed and API call with swagger works to :

[image]

My controller Home :

[image]

If I spy "HttpContext.User.Identity", it filled with my credentials :
[image]

I test the same scenario with a static website, same result.

Is it normal ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like authentication is using NTLM (windows credential of user) and name and password aren't needed.

Comment: Ok, it was my first idea, but why browser show authentication form aned is there a mean to don't display it ?

Comment: Do not know.  Maybe there is different options and you do not have the correct options.  If you are using NTLM then the form is not needed.